# How to call base class method with derived class Object when that method overridden in derived class?

Tags: java

```
class A 
{
  public void m1()
  {
    System.out.println("hi-base class");
  }
}

class B extends A
{
  public void  m1()
  {
    System.out.println("hi-derived ");
  }

  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    B b1=new B();
  }
}
```

In this i want to invoke base class m1 method by using Derived class object without using the super

Comment: This code will not compile.  You should fix that first.

Comment: And why do you need to invoke m1 without super?   This isn't some bar bet is it?

Comment: @Andrew Just it's my requirement not more than that

Comment: C# does what Srikanth want and C++ too! Java does not.

Answer (score 3):

You would need to construct an object of type A. You have overridden method m1 in the derived class, and so any calls to m1 on an object that was created as a B will have the B version of m1 invoked. Without using `super`, there's no way to instruct the compiler to make the non-virtual call to the base-class version.

Comment: Thank u 4 sharing but it is possible to invoke the base class method by using derived class Object i don't know syntax

Comment: That may be, but here's my question: why do you want and/or need to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Are you just looking for `super.m1();`? This will invoke the immediate parent's method.

However, you cannot instantiate an object of type `B` from outside of `B` and use this.

You cannot do:

```
B value = new B();
value.super.m1(); // call A's implementation
```

However, you could do this within B:

```
@Override
public void m1()
{
    System.out.println("hi from B");
    super.m1();
}

public void useAM1()
{
    super.m1();
}
```

Of course, when you start to provide workarounds to get at functionality from `A`, then it sounds like you are abusing inheritance, or *at least* should have used an instance of `A` to begin with.

Interestingly, in C++ you could do this: `value->A::m1();`. *Fortunately*, there is no equivalent in Java.

Comment: For reasons I cannot fathom, OP explicitly wants to avoid using super, and he is quite sure it can be done.

Comment: I was looking at your answer and was just as confused by their response, so I wanted to throw out the explicit `super.m1();` answer just in case he didn't realize its usage.

Answer (score 0):

In short you cannot do it -- virtual dispatching would delegate the call to the referred.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a new feature to Java introduced some time in the past 12 years since this question was asked, but it's possible now.

You can type cast your B object as the A class, then invoke the overridden method to get the A class's version.

```java
b1.m1();       // hi-derived
((A)b1).m1();  // hi-base class
```

You could also instantiate the B object as an A object, in which case this is reversed.

```java
A b1 = new B();
b1.m1();       // hi-base class
((B)b1).m1();  // hi-derived
```

You can't go the reverse direction, though, casting the base class as the derived class. It won't compile.