# Java creating patterns

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have 7 classes that extends one parent abstract class.
Also I have 7 classes that match first classes.

I want to create one object of second classes depending on class first object.

Which pattern I should use?

I think about factory, but sometimes I need to add new classes and there are many of factories. So when I want to add new class I have to add it to all factories.

**Class hierarchy:**
[image: Class hierarchy]

So I have object Super(is abstract) and want to create classes Related depend on real class of object(Child_1 ...)

Also I thought about creating classes Related in Child classes and use polymorphism but I think it breaks single responsibility principle

Comment: Are you asking whether this should be using a Factory/Singleton design?

Comment: I don't think that singleton is appropriate here. I said my opinion about factory and want to know may be there is some other convenient pattern.

Comment: Why are there "many Factories"? I see only one ... Or one factorymethod per "first class". But I don't get why there should be "many"?

Comment: I have many classes depend on first scope. Like class1, class2, ... , class7 ; otherClass1, ..., otherClass7; other1Class1 ...

Comment: It may be useful to edit your question to provide some examples of the classes and hierarchy you are planning to use.  Also, to me, a Factory is useful only if you want to include initialisation code whilst keeping the constructor public for serialization, or have the constructor as private or internal only.

Comment: I added diagram, hope it will be helpful.

Comment: Why are there many factories? Can't you make it generic enough to use just one factory - then the maintenance of adding a new class will be minimal.

Comment: "I want to create one object of second classes depending on class first object" . What do you mean? To create an object, it depends only on one class, not two.

Comment: I mean that I want create Related1 object, concrete class is depend on concrete class of Child object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, with the edited question, my suggestion would be to use a Factory method (since you are keen to use a factory) with local initialisation as and when required.

So you can have a Super factory class that utilises `Class<?>.newInstance` to create a new instance of your sub-classes.  You can then call an internal function say "internalInitialise" and override that in child classes to handle their own non-generic requirements calling the base version first each time as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/6067489/697159 (example calls it last)